# Need Help to make multiple local notifications in ionic 2

Tags: notifications, ionic2

I'm trying to make multiple notification with for loops with different ID's.

I don't know why when I test the codes, only one notification play? The other notification cancelled (not play).

this is my code

```
addNotifications(){

    this.localNotifications.cancelAll();
    this.TempExamsList.forEach(e=>{
        let notificationTime = new Date();
        notificationTime.setFullYear(
        parseInt(moment(e.date,"YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY")),
        parseInt(moment(e.date,"YYYY-MM-DD").format("MM"))-1,
        parseInt(moment(e.date,"YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD")));
        notificationTime.setHours(parseInt(moment(e.time,"HH:mm").format("HH")));
        notificationTime.setMinutes(parseInt(moment(e.time,"HH:mm").format("mm")));
        this.localNotifications.schedule({
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds(),
            title: e.name,
            text: "Location: " + e.location + " - Time: " + e.time,
            at: notificationTime,
            //sound: null,
        });
    })

    this.TempTasksList.forEach(t=>{
        let notificationTime = new Date();
        notificationTime.setFullYear(
        parseInt(moment(t.date,"YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY")),
        parseInt(moment(t.date,"YYYY-MM-DD").format("MM"))-1,
        parseInt(moment(t.date,"YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD")));
        notificationTime.setHours(parseInt(moment(t.time,"HH:mm").format("HH")));
        notificationTime.setMinutes(parseInt(moment(t.time,"HH:mm").format("mm")));
        this.localNotifications.schedule({
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds(),
            title: t.name,
            text: "Time: " + t.time,
            at: notificationTime,
            //sound: null,
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on ionic documentation :

```js
this.localNotifications.schedule([{
   id: 1,
   text: 'Multi ILocalNotification 1',
   sound: isAndroid ? 'file://sound.mp3': 'file://beep.caf',
   data: { secret:key }
  },{
   id: 2,
   title: 'Local ILocalNotification Example',
   text: 'Multi ILocalNotification 2',
   icon: 'http://example.com/icon.png'
}]);
```

Looping condition

```js
this.localNotificationsArray = [];
this.tempTaskList.forEach( data =>{
    this.localNotificationsArray.push({
       id: 1,
       text: data.yourTask,
       title: data.title,
       icon: 'http://example.com/icon.png'
       data: { secret:key }
      }
    });
});
this.localNotifications.schedule(this.localNotificationsArray);
```

Just try , maybe works .
If i were you, i will not load so many item on notification . Just use once , and describe detail in list view.

Your miss is on multiple notification explained using `[]` ex:`this.localNotifications.schedule([])`